# Created Custom fields in Gantt view and want to show up in Resource Usage view

Tags: vba, custom-fields, ms-project

I am using MS Project to list all the projects and work my department is doing.  I have created custom fields (`Text 1(proj name)` and `Text 2 (proj number)`) in my Gantt Chart view for each task and subtask.  How can I create a macro to get these to show up in my Resource Usage view with all the data I entered in at the Gantt Chart view?  I want to see a list of all my resources, what tasks that they are assigned to and see those custom fields for each of those tasks.  Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? please show some source code and state specifically what your problem is

Comment: Here is something I tried but I don't think I have it right.

Comment: Sub test()
'Variables for tracking current task and Resource
Dim T As Task
Dim R As Resource
Dim A As Assignment
Set ts = ActiveProject.Tasks
'Looping through all tasks in the project
For Each T In ActiveProject.Tasks
    'Checking to see if task is blank
    If Not T Is Nothing Then
        'Looping through each Resource for a task
       For Each R In Tasks.Assignment
       If Assignments = T.Name Then
            R.Text1 = T.Text1
       End If
        Next R
    End If
Next T
End Sub

Answer (score 1):

There are two sets of custom fields against assignments. Resource.assignments and task.assignments.

If you reference the assignments via the tasks collection in VBA or the task usage view in the client you'll be updating the task.assignment field.

If you access the assignment via the resources collection or the resource usage view, then it's the resource.assignments field you're updating.

If you want them both to align, you need a routine that steps through all the tasks, then each assignment for each task, then locate the same assignment via the resources collection, and set task.assignments.text21 = resources.assignments.text21 (for example).

This was introduced in 2007 i think - not viewed as a bug by Microsoft, just a new feature.

Comment: So you are saying what I had is close but I just need to correct the mapping for each text field?  My VBA skills are very lacking.  Sorry.

Comment: Reviewing your code sample, you're not actually using the assignment.text1 fields - you're trying to map the task.text1 field to the resource.text1 field, which won't really work as assignments allow a many to many relationship between tasks and resources (i.e. a task can have multiple resources and a resource can be assigned to multiple tasks).

Comment: All your code will do is set the resource.text1 field to the task.text1 field of the last task that they are assigned to. If that last task doesn't have a text1 value, then neither will the resource. You probably want to concatenate the values together so that the resource.text1 field will be a list of all the text1 values for the tasks that resource is assigned to.

Comment: e.g. R.Text1 = R.Text1 & T.Text1

Comment: So you are saying this should work.  'Sub test()
Dim T As Task
Dim R As Resource
Dim A As Assignment
Set ts = ActiveProject.Tasks
For Each T In ActiveProject.Tasks
    If Not T Is Nothing Then
       For Each R In Tasks.Assignment
       If Assignments = T.Name Then
            R.Text1 = R.Text1 & T.Text1
       End If
        Next R
    End If
Next T
End Sub
'

Comment: +1 Thanks for the clarification on the two sets of custom fields for assignments! I updated my code to set the Text1 field on both.

Answer (score 0):

The "task" data you see in the Resource Usage view and the "resource" data you see in the Task Usage view are actually the *Assignment* data.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @Andrew's clarification on the two sets of custom text fields for assignments, I've updated the code so that the task's Text1 field is visible in both the Task Usage view and the Resource Usage view.

Here's a macro that updates the Assignment Text1 field with the task's Text1 field:

```
Sub UpdateAssignmentInfo()
    Dim tsk As Task
    Dim asn As Assignment
    For Each tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks
        For Each asn In tsk.Assignments
            asn.Text1 = tsk.Text1
        Next asn
    Next tsk
    Dim res As Resource
    For Each res In ActiveProject.Resources
        For Each asn In res.Assignments
            asn.Text1 = asn.Task.Text1
        Next asn
    Next res
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.  Something is still wrong.  I ran that macro and still do not get any data populating the Text1 field in the resource usage view.